# How do I wire this 4-way light switch?

Tags: electrical, switch

I have 3 switches that control the same light. One of them broke, so I replaced it. I can't get the light to work now. I got what looked like the same kind of switch from the store. It's a 15amp/120 Volt 4 way switch. All wiring diagrams I've looked at talk about a black wire. This only has 2 reds and 2 whites. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Picture of outlet box]

I've tried lots of combinations with the red and white wires. What's not right here? Do I need a three way switch instead?

Comment: So you going to provide a PN/datasheet for the switch? Is the picture provided the old switch or the one you bought? I assume you hooked the new switch up the same as the old one?

Comment: You may need at least one four way switch... see here.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#More_than_two_locations

Comment: I changed that that "12V" to "120V"; please change it back if I was wrong.

Comment: Where's the second ground? pig tailed?

Answer (score 1):

1st, the white wires should be completely covered with black tape. Try putting both same colors at the top and at the bottom, *if* you have verified all these wires are the travelers from 2, 3-way switches.

[image]

In this diagram the light is off. Toggling any of the switches will turn it on.

[hometoys.com](http://www.hometoys.com/emagazine.php?url=/htinews/feb98/articles/kingery/kingery7.htm)

Comment: I should have taken a picture of the switch that I removed so I can match up the wiring connections. Are you suggesting putting both red wires at the top and both white wires at the bottom?

Comment: @MattKaye That's how I'd of done it.

Comment: Note that the middle switch is a "4 way" switch.  The other two are "3 way" switches.  It is okay to use a 4 way as a 3 way–one terminal will not be used in that case.

Comment: @mazura, that didn't work. Maybe this other pic will help http://imgur.com/VpTAn4q